# async/await not working with mongoose instance methods

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, mongoose-schema

I'm try to create user mongoose document which require a storage path. I want to await for directory to be created and path resolved. But it is not working and after user is saved, user.storagePath is still undefined. please figure out problem.

**Following is code of createStorage()**

```
const getMountRoot = require('../configuration/configuration').getMountRoot
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const Logger = require('../configuration/configuration').getLogger

module.exports = (email, firstName, secondName) => {
  email = String(email).toLowerCase().replace(/[@_\.\-]/g, '')
  firstName = String(firstName).toLowerCase().replace(/[@_\.\-]/g, '')
  secondName = String(secondName).toLowerCase().replace(/[@_\.\-]/g, '')

  let storagePath = path.join(getMountRoot(), `${secondName}${email}${firstName}`)
  return fs.promises.mkdir(storagePath, { recursive: true })
    .then(() => { return storagePath })
    .catch(() => {Logger.log(err); return storagePath})
}
```

**And following is instance method**

```
const createStorage = require('../extra/create-storage')

userSchema.methods.createStorage = async function() {
  this.storagePath = await createStorage(this.email, this.firstName, this.secondName)
}
```

Kindly note that I call `createStorage()` on `User` instance before calling the `save()`

Comment: Do you `await` the `createStorage` call when calling it on the model instance? Seeing the code would help.

Comment: @qqilihq No I did't do that, can that help?

Comment: @qqilihq await when calling instance method worked, can you just explain why do I need to do that? For example if it goes down in multiple function calls, then do I need to wait at lower call like this instance or all call leading to createStorage()?

Comment: Yes, basically you'll need to wait “all the way up”. Alternatively, you could move the `save()` into the instance method and call it something like `createStorageAndSave` or maybe use one of the `pre` hooks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @qqilihq figured, I need to await at instance method call. Doing that worked correctly.